# Back to previous page (cancel behavior)

Tags: django, django-templates, django-allauth

I want to add a button in the logout page for cancel the process. Like here:

```html
<h1 class="h1">{% trans "Sign Out" %}</h1>

<p class="lead">{% trans 'Are you sure you want to sign out?' %}</p>

<form id="logout_form" class="logout" method="post" action="{% url 'account_logout' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% if redirect_field_value %}
  <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
  {% endif %}
  <a class="btn btn-danger btn-block" type="submit" href="#?">{% trans 'Cancel' %}</a>
  <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" type="submit">{% trans 'Sign Out' %}</button>
</form>
```

I want to if user clicked Cancel they back to previous page, where they are coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this using [`request.META.HTTP_REFERER`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META):

```
<form id="logout_form" class="logout" method="post" action="{% url 'account_logout' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% if request.META.HTTP_REFERER %}
  <a class="btn btn-danger btn-block" href="{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}">{% trans 'Cancel' %}</a>
  {% endif %}
  <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" type="submit">{% trans 'Sign Out' %}</button>
</form>
```